# Why is my tooltip flashing on and off?

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am creating a tooltip after [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569).

For some reason, my tooltip flashes on and off as I move the mouse. As I understand it, the `mousemove()` function finds the closest datapoint; so as long as the mouse is over the `.overlay` rectangle, the tooltip should always be showing.

Any ideas? Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/zhMQ8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's to do the the `mouseover`/`mouseout` continuosly firing when they needn't:

updated fiddle (again): http://jsfiddle.net/zhMQ8/3/

```
g.on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); });

g.on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); });

g.select(".overlay").on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

Comment: Hmm, still flashing for me. Very bizarre.

Comment: changing the mouseover/mouseout to the `g` rather than the `.overlay` seems to work.

Answer (score 22):

The flickering happens because the tooltip sometimes appears below the mouse and causes *mouseout* be called and that again removes the tooltip and again the mouse is over the element so *mouseover* is called and the cycle continues...

Make a little gap (where I added 5), so the tooltip won't come under the mouse:

```
tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + (xScale(d.date)   + 5  ) + ",0)");
```

**EDIT**
Another, maybe a better, way to avoid the tooltip affecting the mouse is to give it styling:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: Oh god... thank you!, this answer should be the correct one.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` on the tooltip div fixed my issue with it continuous firing. It's because the mouse cursor moves into the tooltip when it appears and this triggers the mouseleave event on the node.

Answer (score 0):

Found if tool tip extends off of form will cause this issue.  Move tooltip inboard from edge of screen or shorten tool tip text.

Answer (score -3):

don't use mousemove properties. Use Mouse Hover.

```
    private void pboxLabExam_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(pboxLabExamGlow, "LABORATORY EXAM"); //<---
    }
```

Comment: This is a JS question, is the snippet related? is it java?